# android - any way to track webview history like wv.canGoBack()?

Tags: android, webview

Is there a way I can have my own history stack for webview?

It sounds to me that `webview.canGoBack()` similar to `stack.peek()`, and `webview.goBack()` similar to `stack.pop()`. I wanted to have a way to create my own stack that keeps the webview history because I want to add additional info to the stack depends on the page that is currently being viewed, and this stack might have non-url strings. This is why I wanted to create my own custom stack instead of using the native methods.

I tried to create a `stack` and add piece of info when `onPageStarted` is called. then I realized there are several redirects happen would cause `onPageStarted` being called several times within a page.

Let's say I start from pageA -> pageB -> pageC. there are 1 redirect happen on pageA and 2 redirects happen on pageB. what's gonna happen is:

by using `webview.goBack()`, my page go from pageC -> pageB -> pageA. this is exactly the behavior I want.

but when using my custom stack, my page go from pageC -> pageB -> pageB-> pageB -> pageA -> pageA

is htere a way that I can create a custom stack that has the same behavior as `webview.goBack()`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to override the WebViewClient function [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) which gets called
before a new url is loaded, and which allows you to peek its value. Your implementation can then store all visited urls:

```
ArrayList<String> visitedUrlStack = new ArrayList<String>();

 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              visitedUrlStack.add(url);
              return false; // continue with loading of url!!
         }
});
```

You can interrogate visitedUrlStack at any point in your program for a list of visited urls.

It is important that your implimentation of shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will return false. This implies
to the webview that it can go on loading the url.

Comment: I tried `onPageStarted`, `onPageFinished` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`. all three of them are being called multiple times depending on how many redirects happen on that page.

Comment: maybe redirects aren't added to webview stack. only clicks on the page would count?